# How to use GPU parameters in LGBMClassifier and GridSearchCV at Kaggle Platform?

Tags: python, gpu, kaggle, lightgbm, gridsearchcv

I have used lgbclassifier and GridSearchCV, what should be the parameters to use GPU on Kaggle notebook?
[image]

Comment: The parameter to add is "device" : "gpu". You also want to make sure lightgbm-gpu is properly installed for your kaggle notebook (see here to do so https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/GPU-Tutorial.html).

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you add the argument to the last part of the first line like this?

```
........lgb.sklearn.LGBMClassifier(device='gpu')
```